# How to replace any in Linq

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have a Linq query that fetches data from database. The problem is I am using "any" to find out If the user has a role which is in api role table. The query is below and it is working with dummy data; but whenever I run the query against to database i receive *Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator.*

`_apiRepository.GetQueryable<ApiInstance>()
.SelectMany(apiInstance => apiInstance.ApiInstanceRoles)
.Where(apiInstanceRole =>
CurrentUser.UsersInRoles.Any(cr => cr.RoleId == apiInstanceRole.RoleId))`

Comment: @JohanLarsson: `Contains` requires an object, not a predicate ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try rewriting the query with `Contains`, like this:

```
_apiRepository
    .GetQueryable<ApiInstance>()
    .SelectMany(apiInstance => apiInstance.ApiInstanceRoles)
    .Where(apiInstanceRole => CurrentUser
        .UsersInRoles
        .Select(cr =>cr.RoleId)
        .Contains(apiInstanceRole.RoleId))
```

Comment: First query looks ok. Second one does not work as type of ApiInstanceRole and UserInRole are not same.

Comment: @GeorgeJove Thanks! I removed the part of the answer that did not work.