# Source String: linq find any (array) and replace

Tags: c#, arrays, string, linq

I did review the following, it did help in some aspects, but not to find a final solution:

[C# replace strings in array with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28740009/c-sharp-replace-strings-in-array-with-linq)

[Replacing characters in a string array with linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26823974/replacing-characters-in-a-string-array-with-linq)

[Linq to SQL replace .Any() with .Contains()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736221/linq-to-sql-replace-any-with-contains)

[How to replace any in Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14091064/how-to-replace-any-in-linq)

[string replace using Linq in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137514/string-replace-using-linq-in-c-sharp)
This one might work, but I am currently not sure if it is worth the effect converting all the code using lists in stead of arrays

[Replacing values in a list inside a Linq query with values from a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61238950/replacing-values-in-a-list-inside-a-linq-query-with-values-from-a-dictionary)

Extract from the source document:

> Albania Euro 97
> Algeria Euro 110
> Angola US $ 303  Antigua and
> Barbuda US $ 220
> Argentina US $ 133
> Armenia US $ 220
> Austria Euro> 131
> Australia A $ 230
> Azarbaijani US $ 145

The source document (only pdf, after many requests and years still no CSV, etc.) contain multiple version of the same currency.
Example: USD

- US $
- US (S)
- etc.

Have setup the follow arrays to try and provide some sort of standardization:

*Which works well*

```
var incCurrDollar = new[] { "US dollar ($)", "US ($)", "US $" };
var incCurrEuro = new[] { "Euro (€)", "Euro" };
var incCurrPound = new[] { "Pounds Sterling (£)", "British Pounds" };
var incCurrAus = new[] { "Australian $", "A ($)", "Australian ($)" };
var incCurrZAR = new[] { "RSA Rand (R)", "RSA Rand", "Rand" };
var incCurrKHN = new[] { "Hong Kong ($)", "Hong Kong $", "HK $" };
var incCurrNZL = new[] { "New Zealand ($)", "New Zealand $", "NZ $" };
```

Employeed in the following way:

```
if (rCurrency == "")
{
   rCurrency = incCurrAus.Any(x => exRowCurrent.Contains(x)) ? "Australian ($)" : "";
   rCurrencyUnit = incCurrAus.Any(x => exRowCurrent.Contains(x)) ? "AUD" : "";
}
```

Is there a way to also replace the applicable content of exRowCurrent with the standardize version?

Comment: Isn't this a search and replace job?

Comment: Yes, but is there a quick and simple way to do it?
Potencially something like this:
foreach (var repCurreny in incCurrAus)
{
   exRowCurrent.Replace(exRowCurrent, repCurreny);
}

Comment: What does quick refer to, quick replacement or quick coding? I think the way is simple enough. If you mean quick coding, I think it's also quick enough, you just need several for loops.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the most quick and simple way (It just seemed too simple :) )

```
rCurrency = incCurrAus.Any(x => exRowCurrent.Contains(x)) ? "Australian ($)" : "";
rCurrencyUnit = incCurrAus.Any(x => exRowCurrent.Contains(x)) ? "AUD" : "";
foreach (var repCurrency in incCurrAus)
{
   exRowCurrent = exRowCurrent.Replace(repCurrency, rCurrency);
}
```